# How to resolve the Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to build demo App using room database to understand how it works .The issue that I am facing is when i try to run my App , it give me above  error mentioned. I will even attached the error code from logcat.Below are my build.gradle files

build.gradle(app)

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.worddirectory'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.worddirectory"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildToolsVersion '33.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1"
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.4.0"

    // Dependencies for working with Architecture components
    // You'll probably have to update the version numbers in build.gradle (Project)

    // Room components
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0-alpha01"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1"
    kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0-alpha01'

    // Lifecycle components
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.0"

    // Kotlin components
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.10"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.8.10"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.8.10"

    // UI
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0"

    // Testing
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.13.2"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:2.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation ("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0", {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5"
}
```

build.gradle(project level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.0' apply false
}
```

**Below is the error show in Logcat after I try to run the app.**
Caused by: `org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`